# PHP strip_tags plus htmlspecialchars

Tags: mysql, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

Whenever I input into database I use the `strip_tags` function and whenever I output information I use `htmlspecialchars`. That said, if I introduce into database something like:

```
Hello, Mr. John. "Come on.."
```

The output is:

```
Hello, Mr. John. \"Come on..\"
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: use `echo stripslashes($value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using htmlspecialchars on your output, the result you get is `\&quot;Come on..\&quot;` unless ENT_NOQUOTES is set.

To get the original string `Hello, Mr. John. "Come on.."` you have to

`$result = htmlspecialchars_decode( stripslashes($raw) );`

or 
`$result = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($raw), ENT_NOQUOTES);` when you're calling htmlspecialchars